# Linear Multistep Method With No Spurious Fixed Points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

For a general linear multistep method, i.e. a method of the form

$\sum_{j=0}^s \alpha_j x_{n+j} = \triangle t \sum_{j=0}^s \beta_j f(x_{n+j})$

Is there any way to manipulate the coefficients $\alpha_j$ and $\beta_j$ in order to ensure that the method inherits all fixed points of the underlying ODE and no spurious ones?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example where you get spurious fixed points? I can imagine getting periodic cycles, but not the $x_n$ becoming constant without the $f(x_n)$ becoming zero.

Comment: The fixed points $y^*$ being a solution to the method is the same as saying $y_{n+s}=y_{n+s-1}=...=y_n = y^*$ is a solution to the method

Comment: Yes, and that implies that $0=f(y^*)$ directly from the consistency conditions of the method, so that $y^*$ is a regular fixed point of the system.